# How to wait for all observable within a mutable array to finish in RxSwift

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

My expectation is to add observables on-the-fly (eg: images upload), let them start, and, when I finished dynamically enqueueing everything, wait for all observable to be finished.

Here is my class :

```
open class InstantObservables<T> {
    lazy var disposeBag = DisposeBag()

    public init() { }

    lazy var observables: [Observable<T>] = []
    lazy var disposables: [Disposable] = []

    open func enqueue(observable: Observable<T>) {
        observables.append(observable)

        let disposable = observable
            .subscribe()

        disposables.append(disposable)

        disposable
            .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
    }

    open func removeAndStop(atIndex index: Int) {
        guard observables.indices.contains(index)
            && disposables.indices.contains(index) else {
            return
        }
        let disposable = disposables.remove(at: index)
        disposable.dispose()

        _ = observables.remove(at: index)
    }

    open func waitForAllObservablesToBeFinished() -> Observable<[T]> {
        let multipleObservable = Observable.zip(observables)
        observables.removeAll()
        disposables.removeAll()
        return multipleObservable
    }

    open func cancelObservables() {
        disposeBag = DisposeBag()
    }
}
```

But when I subscribe to the observable sent by `waitForAllObservablesToBeFinished()` , all of them are re-executed (which is logic, regarding how Rx works).

How could I warranty that each are executed once, whatever the number of subscription is ?

Answer (score 0):

While writing the question, I got the answer !
By altering the observable through `shareReplay(1)`, and enqueuing and subscribing to this altered observable.. It works !

Here is the updated code :

```
open class InstantObservables<T> {
    lazy var disposeBag = DisposeBag()

    public init() { }

    lazy var observables: [Observable<T>] = []
    lazy var disposables: [Disposable] = []

    open func enqueue(observable: Observable<T>) {
        let shared = observable.shareReplay(1)
        observables.append(shared)

        let disposable = shared
            .subscribe()

        disposables.append(disposable)

        disposable
            .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
    }

    open func removeAndStop(atIndex index: Int) {
        guard observables.indices.contains(index)
            && disposables.indices.contains(index) else {
            return
        }
        let disposable = disposables.remove(at: index)
        disposable.dispose()

        _ = observables.remove(at: index)
    }

    open func waitForAllObservablesToBeFinished() -> Observable<[T]> {
        let multipleObservable = Observable.zip(observables)
        observables.removeAll()
        disposables.removeAll()
        return multipleObservable
    }

    open func cancelObservables() {
        disposeBag = DisposeBag()
    }
}
```